# C2x: what is the rationale for alignas to be a keyword rather than a macro?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, backwards-compatibility

In 1990 P.J. Plauger wrote (emphasis added):

> Standard C offers you an additional level of security, however. It is a level
> offered in no other language standard that I know. It promises that if you avoid
> certain sets of names, *you will experience no collisions*. Thus, Standard C makes
> it that much easier to write highly portable applications.

In C11 keyword `_Alignas` (for example) was introduced with the accompanying macro `alignas` defined in `<stdalign.h>`. Here we see that the keyword is `_Alignas`, not `alignas` (since in pre-C11 `alignas` is not reserved). Hence, there is no collision with possible user-defined `alignas`.

However, in C2x the `alignas` is a keyword and `<stdalign.h>` provides no content (and C2x says nothing about `__alignas_is_defined` macro -- defect?). It means that in C2x any pre-C2x code containing user-defined `alignas` will cause semantics violation and, hence, breaks backward compatibility.

Questions:

1. Does it mean that since C2x the "you will experience no collisions" does not hold any longer?
2. What is the rationale for `alignas` (for example) to be a keyword rather than a macro?

Comment: The proposal for it (https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2934.pdf) argues that this approach has not been consistent in general. E.g.: `restrict` was added as a lowercase keyword in C99

Comment: Similarly `bool`, `true` and `false` will also become keywords in C23. I would think that compatibility with C++ was a stronger argument than backwards compatibility with old junk code.

Comment: The proposal referred to by @UnholySheep also puts emphasis on compatibility with C++. I think the proposal answers the question well.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Re: "now": indeed. Fixed.

Comment: @UnholySheep Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proposal for these change (available at https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2934.pdf) argues that the naming strategy in regards to new keywords has already been inconsistent with previous standard versions:

> some were integrated using non-reserved names (`const`, `inline`) others
> were integrated in an underscore-capitalized form. For some of them, the use of the lower-case form then
> is ensured via a set of library header files.

Further using the same keyword naming as C++ (for compatibility purposes) is also mentioned in the proposal, since some keywords originated in that language and were later added to C.